# How can we edit the placeholder text in "Ask Question"?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

In "Ask Question" (on Ethereum SE not this meta) how can we edit it so it's simply "What's your Ethereum question? Be specific."

Currently our placeholder text is very long.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/202/87), as it seems to use the `$Topic` variable.

Comment: this was fixed along with the `$Topic` just today, see comment by Shog9 on my answer linked above.